# Facebook Login Failing on Test Server

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate using facebook I've setup a simple html page on my web server (Web Server 2008 R2).

When I go onto my page and click the login button I get a dialog that says:
"Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again."

The console says:
"Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

I've got it setup as as a Test App in facebook with the domain and SiteURL set to http://localhost and I've put my public IP into the whitelist field and I've add http://localhost to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field.

This is the code. (I've removed my appID for this example)

```
<body>
   <input type="button" onclick="fbLogIt();" value="Testing Login">
   <div id="status"></div>
</body>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) 
  {
   console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected')
{
  testAPI();
}
else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
{
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
}
}

  function checkLoginState()
  {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response)
  {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
  {
  FB.init({
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version: 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response)
  {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

 };

 // Load the SDK asynchronously
 (function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});
}

 function fbLogIt()
 {
  FB.login(function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
          console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
          FB.api('/me', function (response) {
              console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
          });
      } else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    });
     }
```

Comment: Can you actually provide your appID? That is not sensitive data and can help with debugging your issue.